# How do I access the styled object from the value of a setter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

I am attempting to style every `DataRecordPresenter` in a `XamDataGrid` according to a `VisualBrush` that should flex according to the presenter in question. Specifically I'm aiming to highlight some rows, where the highlighting pattern is potentially complex (i.e. arbitrarily large, albeit in practice probably not more than 5-6 colours).

The solution I'm hoping to use looks something like this:

```
<!-- idp bound to namespace for Infragistics DataPresenters -->
<idp:XamDataGrid>
    <idp:XamDataGrid.Resources>
         <Style TargetType={x:Type idp:DataRecordPresenter>
             <Style.Setters>
                <!-- THE RELATIVESOURCE FAILS HERE -->
                <Setter Property="Tag">
                    <Grid DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,TargetType={x:Type idp:DataRecordPresenter}}}>
                        <!-- Content that relies on properties of the DataRecordPresenter -->
                    </Grid>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <!-- THE RELATIVESOURCE WORKS HERE -->
                    <VisualBrush
                     ViewPort="12,12,12,12" 
                     Visual="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,TargetType={x:Type idp:DataRecordPresenter}}"
                     >
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter>
             </Style.Setters>
         </Style>
    </idp:XamDataGrid.Resources>
</idp:XamDataGrid>
```

The issue is that whilst I am able to identify the DataRecordPresenter when constructing the actual `VisualBrush` (tested using Snoop - as intended the result is the contents of the `Tag` property), whilst trying to find the same object via the same mechanism from the context of the setter for the Tag property, I fail to identify any such ancestor.

I suspect this is because the Tag property is not associated with the visual (or logical) trees, whereas `Background` is, but I haven't managed to come up with a solution as yet that addresses the issue. I'd equally be happy to move the Grid into the `VisualBrush`, but I believe a `VisualBrush` is *also* detached from the relevant trees, so I don't think that'll work, or at least not with a simple inline definition.

Comment: Whilst I'm still interested in a solution to this, the eventual approach was to make use of an attached property on the DataGrid and create/assign Brush instances in a just-in-time manner as records scrolled into or out of the visible window. This is obviously prone to overwriting existing bindings, but worked for my use-case where there weren't any. And ended up being a lot more easy to understand what was going on and why.